# Horizontally align multiline list of figure entries with dotted line in KOMA-script

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, scrreprt

Is there a way to horizontally align multiline caption entries in the list of figures with the dotted line of singleline entries? Since I use the KOMA-script class scrreprt I want to avoid packages like `tocloft`. The picture below should outline the desired result. This might also apply to other lists like list of tables, list of listings, ... . Thanks!

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Single line entry}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Long figure caption that spans over two or more lines should be aligned with the 
dotted line above long figure caption that spans over two or more lines should be aligned with the dotted line above}
    \end{figure}
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```latex
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}% remark: fontsize=11pt is default

\makeatletter
\let\@tocrmarg\@pnumwidth
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Single line entry}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Long figure caption that spans over two or more lines should be aligned with the 
    dotted line above long figure caption that spans over two or more lines should 
    be aligned with the dotted line above}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the dotted lines do not stop at the last dot in the row. There is some space after this last dot.

The default value of `\@pnumwidth` is 1.55em and of `\@tocrmarg` is 2.55em.

If the multiline entries should align with the last dot of the dotted line you have to adjust `\@tocrmarg` to your needs:

```latex
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}% remark: fontsize=11pt is default

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@tocrmarg}{1.85em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Single line entry}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Long figure caption that spans over two or more lines should be aligned with the 
    dotted line above long figure caption that spans over two or more lines should 
    be aligned with the dotted line above}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I understand from your answer that there is no way to set the lengths `\@pnumwidth` to the width of widest page number and then `\@tocrmarg` according to the dotted line automatically.